# How to get the project directory in pyinvoke?

Tags: python, pyinvoke

In my `pyinvoke` task library, I would like to know the **project directory** so I can derive default locations for the directories like `src`, `test`, and `dist`.

Currently, the only way I can see to do this is from `context.config._project_prefix`.

Is there a *better* way to get the project directory?  One that doesn't require the use of an underscore-prefixed (private, subject to change) attribute?  Alternatively, what's the reason for why no such public attribute exists?

Comment: maybe [here](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/issues/831)?

Answer (score 0):

What I've often done is to use `__file__` in my tasks.py and find the project root relative to that.

For example:

```
myproject
    dist
    src
    test
    tasks.py
```

```py
# In tasks.py

from pathlib import Path

project_dir = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
```